# How to add an accordion effect to UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview, cocoa-touch

Here is the current screen:
[image: The current screen]

As you can see, this is list of services that are provided. I retrieved the data from my company's api and the table view cells are populated dynamically.

Here is how it is supposed to work:
[image: How it looks on Android]
[image: The desired functionality]

On clicking one of the cells, an accordion like effect should expand the cell and reveal further details of a particular service. Clicking on it again or clicking on a different service should close it. How should I implement this?

Here's the code for the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ServiceCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...
Service * serviceObject;
serviceObject = [servicesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//Configuring the images
Image * air = [[Image alloc] initWithLocation:@"icons/air.png" andWithServiceID:21];
Image * pest = [[Image alloc] initWithLocation:@"icons/pest.png" andWithServiceID:18];
Image * carpenter = [[Image alloc] initWithLocation:@"icons/carpenter" andWithServiceID:16];
Image * laundry = [[Image alloc] initWithLocation:@"icons/laundry" andWithServiceID:20];
Image * electrician = [[Image alloc] initWithLocation:@"icons/electrician.png" andWithServiceID:17];
Image * plumber = [[Image alloc] initWithLocation:@"icons/plumber.png" andWithServiceID:14];
Image * appliance = [[Image alloc] initWithLocation:@"icons/appliance.png" andWithServiceID:15];

NSArray * images = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:air.location], [UIImage imageNamed:pest.location], [UIImage imageNamed:carpenter.location], [UIImage imageNamed:laundry.location], [UIImage imageNamed:electrician.location], [UIImage imageNamed:plumber.location], [UIImage imageNamed:appliance.location], nil];

if([serviceObject.serviceID isEqualToNumber:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:air.serviceID]]){
    cell.imageView.image = images[0];
}else if([serviceObject.serviceID isEqualToNumber:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:pest.serviceID]]){
    cell.imageView.image = images[1];
}else if([serviceObject.serviceID isEqualToNumber:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:carpenter.serviceID]]){
    cell.imageView.image = images[2];
}else if([serviceObject.serviceID isEqualToNumber:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:laundry.serviceID]]){
    cell.imageView.image = images[3];
}else if([serviceObject.serviceID isEqualToNumber:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:electrician.serviceID]]){
    cell.imageView.image = images[4];
}else if([serviceObject.serviceID isEqualToNumber:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:plumber.serviceID]]){
    cell.imageView.image = images[5];
}else{
    cell.imageView.image = images[6];
}

//Setting the row labels
cell.textLabel.text = serviceObject.serviceName;

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

return cell;
```

}

I'm currently using Xcode 6.3.2 with the latest iPhone SDK.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: post part of your code about cellForRowAtIndexPath and numberOfRowsInSection and didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Take a look at my answer below - this is what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should insert new cell (or several) to you table view ob click. And register the click, for you to know, which cell selected

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [tableView beginUpdates];  
    if(self.selectedCellPath) { //Index path for already expanded cell

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[self.selectedCellPath] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    }

    //if we clicked already expanded cell we just clear everything
    if([self.selectedCellPath isEqual:indexPath]) {
       self.selectedCellPath = nil;
    }
    else {
        self.selectedCellPath = indexPath;

        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[self.selectedCellPath] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    }
    [tableView endUpdates];
```

}

And, in you `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
if([indexPath isEqual:self.selectedCellPath]) {
   //Create your specific cell with text fields
}
else {
   //Create your common cell 
   //Your code for cell creation from question post actually goes here
}
```

**Update 1**

A little performance advice - move all this `Image *` code to `viewDidLoad` method. And make your `NSArray *images` a property for your controller. 'Cause in your variant, you create it each time table view asks for cell. You don't need this. Do it once - `viewDidLoad` is the right place for doing such things

Comment: But if i move it to the `viewDidLoad`, then my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` cannot access them. What should I do?

Comment: Save them into "@property NSArray *images" of your controller

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I'll work on the accordion effect now

Comment: Good luck! Have questions - feel free to ask. End post on success, please

Comment: Sorry. The need for the accordion was eliminated due to some decisions. It works none the less. Thanks

Comment: @Mehul hehe, you got me!

Comment: @SergiiMartynenkoJr, i am just kidding friend.

Comment: @Mehul, appreciate that

Comment: @SergiiMartynenkoJr, yes Defiantly